# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined (using Google Maps API)

Tags: javascript, django

I'm building a site using Django and when I wanted to put a map with markers(which coordinates I pull from database) it refuses to show the markers, throwing out the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

On every single occurance of:(3rd  block)

```
var map = google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
```

Here's the whole code:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 60%"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 53.132330, lng: 23.159630},
          zoom: 12
        });
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDIOOtr2iADzkBWq3r48fHiZRvnAFcWxHY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  {% for place in recent_attraction %}
    <script>
      var map = google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
      function setMarker() {
        var latlng = {lat: {{place.gps_x}}, lng: {{place.gps_y}}}
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
          })
      }
    </script>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Looks like you call the function before the Google library is loaded.

Comment: How do I fix it? The google map api loads asynchronously, second <script> block loads it afaik.

Comment: Well what is calling `initMap`? You should try to postpone the call until the library is loaded.

Comment: I'm honestly clueless what calls it, but the map loads perfectly fine, maybe the problem is that the markers want to set on the loaded map, at least that's what I think.

Comment: ha no, I think I know what the problem is, in your second `<script>` fragment, you use `google` immediately. I suggest that you inject the `var map = ...` into the function itself.

Comment: Okay, that removed the error, thanks. The problem sadly still persists as I still cannot see the markers on the map, I'll check if everything is ok with coordinates in database.

Comment: This may be stupid of me, but {function setMarker() ... } is a function that I made myself - I'm really rusty, but is it a static function after all? the { initMap() } function launched itself afterall.

Comment: I think you better indeed add markers in the `initMap`, furthermore right now you define `setMarker` multiple times, since the loop simply generates multiple such `<script>`s.

Comment: Huh, good idea. I didn't even think i could do {% ... %} blocks inside a <script>. I'll try to come up with something then let you know how it went :D

Comment: Well Django templating actually does not know anything about HTML/JavaScript at all. It simply sees tags like `{% for ... %}` and `{{place.gps_x}}` and replaces that, and performs loops. The rest (the non-Django tag parts) are simply emitted, but the template engine does *not* "interpret" these. It does not care what the HTML is saying.

Comment: Works. I own you a beer. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the title was removed by moving `var map = google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));` inside the function. That didn't remove the problem completely, as I still didn't get the markers on my map. The solution was to move the code inside a single  block and a single function, like this:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 60%"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 53.132330, lng: 23.159630},
          zoom: 12
        });
        {% for place in recent_attraction %}
        var latlng = {lat: {{place.gps_x}}, lng: {{place.gps_y}}}
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
          });
          {% endfor %}
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDIOOtr2iADzkBWq3r48fHiZRvnAFcWxHY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Thanks to user Willem Van Onsem.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference error seems to be caused by the order that you have your code executing.

Additionally you could create a function to handle adding your markers. I am at work so I cannot test the following code, but it should get you on the right path.

```
<div id="map" style="height: 60%"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDIOOtr2iADzkBWq3r48fHiZRvnAFcWxHY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<script>
    var map;
    function setMarker(lat, long) {
        var latlng = {lat: lat, lng: long}
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });
    }
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 53.132330, lng: 23.159630},
            zoom: 12
        });
    }
</script>
{% for place in recent_attraction %}
    <script>
        setMarker({{place.gps_x}},{{place.gps_y}});
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```